# Running main method with IntelliJ in gradle project, but with only the System.out output

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I have a project configured with gradle. And I use IntelliJ to run the main method as follows

[image: Printscreen]

Yet, I don't want to see the main Gradle console showing me the results, I just want to see the same output as IntelliJ when running a project that is not configured with Gradle

Basically, I don't want to see

[image]

Nor this:

[image]

Is it possible?

Answer (score 6):

In IntelliJ go to File -> Settings -> Build,Execution,Development -> Build Tools -> Gradle.

And, Change the property "Build and run using:" to IntelliJ IDEA from Gradle(Default).

This will give you the same output as IntelliJ when running a project that is not configured with Gradle.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can change the run option to not use Gradle at File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle:

[image: Gradle no delegate]

Comment: Well, I want to use Gradle, I just don't want the extra output in the console. I want to see only what comes out of System.out/err etc.

Comment: You can try console folding feature, but there is no way to hide it completely: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-console-folding.html. Request is welcome at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA.